# Flutter provider state management, logout concept

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I am trying to implement custom logout solution for my application, where no matter where user currently is, once the `Logout button` is clicked, app will navigate back to `Login page`.

My idea was, that instead of listening on every component for state changes, I would have one single listener on a master component -> `MyApp`.

For the sake of simplicity, I have stripped down items to bare minimum. Here is how my Profile class could look like:

```
class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthentificated = false;
  bool get isAuthentificated => _isAuthentificated;
  set isAuthentificated(bool newVal) {
    _isAuthentificated = newVal;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now, under `Main`, I have registered this provider as following:

```
void main() => runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => Profile(),
          )
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
```

And finally `MyApp` component:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Profile>(
      builder: (context, profile, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 121, 107),
            accentColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 87, 34),
          ),
          home: buildBasePage(context, profile),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildBasePage(BuildContext context, Profile currentProfile) {
    return !currentProfile.isAuthentificated
        ? LoginComponent()
        : MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page test');
  }
}
```

My idea was, that as `MyApp` component is the **master**, I should be able to create a consumer, which would be notified if current user is authentificated, and would respond accordingly.

What happens is, that when I am in e.g. `MyHomePage` component and I click `Logout()` method which looks like following:

```
  void _logout() {
    Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false).isAuthentificated = false;
  }
```

I would be expecting that upon changing property, the initial `MyApp` component would react and generate `LoginPage`; which is not the case. I have tried changing from `Consumer` to `Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false)` yet with the same result.

What do I need to do in order for this concept to work? Is it even correct to do it this way?

I mean I could surely update my `Profile` class in a way, that I add the following method:

```
  logout(BuildContext context) {
    _isAuthentificated = false;

    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginComponent()));
  }
```

And then simply call `Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false).logout()`, however I thought that Provider package was designed for this...or am I missing something?

Any help in respect to this matter would be more than appreciated.

Comment: As an overall approach in general, I don't think I would use this idea. The animation for the page transitions can't be controlled. It is just a sudden switch.

Comment: I faced the same problem, did you find why it does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it wasn't working for you. Here is a complete example I built based on your description. It works!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthentificated = false;

  bool get isAuthentificated {
    return this._isAuthentificated;
  }

  set isAuthentificated(bool newVal) {
    this._isAuthentificated = newVal;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Profile>(
          create: (final BuildContext context) {
            return Profile();
          },
        )
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Profile>(
      builder: (final BuildContext context, final Profile profile, final Widget child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
          home: profile.isAuthentificated ? MyHomePage() : MyLoginPage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Home [Auth Protected]")),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: const Text("Logout"),
          onPressed: () {
            final Profile profile = Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false);
            profile.isAuthentificated = false;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Login")),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: const Text("Login"),
          onPressed: () {
            final Profile profile = Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false);
            profile.isAuthentificated = true;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of provider package did you use? I used 4.0+

Comment: I used the most recent. ^4.0.3

Comment: Interesting; when I copy pasted your solution into my code, it now works like a charm! Anyway I am marking your solution as done. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass `listen:false`, instead simply call

`Provider.of<Profile>(context).logout()`

So your Profile class would look like

```
      class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isAuthentificated = false;


  logout() {
    isAuthentificated = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: But my problem is, that with current implementation nothing happens. What should I change in order for Provider package to work?

Comment: it should work as per the provider package documentation, otherwise open an issue on github for provider package.