# Go back to login when logged out from the drawer, no matter what

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I need to redirect user to login page when he clicks on logout button from drawer (wherever he is). The problem is that when I click on the logout button, the screen remains the same.

According to this post: [Flutter provider state management, logout concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108556/flutter-provider-state-management-logout-concept)

I have:

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Profile>(
          create: (final BuildContext context) {
            return Profile();
          },
        )
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

MyApp:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  /// Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        // ...
        home: Consumer<Profile>(
          builder: (context, profile, child){
             return profile.isAuthenticated ? SplashScreen() : AuthScreen();
          }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The part of the drawer where there is the logout button:

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
    title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.logout),
    onTap: () async {
      SharedPreferences preferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await preferences.clear();

      final Profile profile =
          Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false);
      profile.isAuthenticated = false;
    }),
```

As I said, when I click on the logout button from the drawer, the user is correctly logged out, but the screen remains the same.

**UPDATE**

This is the profile class:

```
class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  bool get isAuthenticated {
    return this._isAuthenticated;
  }

  set isAuthenticated(bool newVal) {
    this._isAuthenticated = newVal;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/routeName") in LogOut onTap() Section.

For more information : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html

Make sure to have logout route set in MyApp file, and i'd edit logout button file as such:

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
    title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.logout),
    onTap: () async {
      SharedPreferences preferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await preferences.clear();

      final Profile profile =
          Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false);
      profile.isAuthenticated = false;

      // add login file route here using Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() ; 
    }),
```

Comment: What you mean with `Make sure to have logout route set in MyApp file`? And, I could put `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`, but I use provider to avoid that part of code. The provider should do this job for me.

Comment: Why not check out the this video by TheNetNinja, https://youtu.be/j_SJ7XmT2MM

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using provider class incorrectly.
use your profile class like this.

```
    class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
           bool _isAuthenticated = true;

           bool get getIsAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

           set setIsAuthenticated(bool isAuthenticated) {
                  _isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
                 notifyListeners();//you must call this method to inform lisners
                }
}
```

in set method call `notifyListners();`

in your listTile
replace  `profile.isAuthenticated = false`  to `profile.isAuthenticated = false;`
Always use getters and setters for best practice.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I use `notifyListeners` in my Profile class :(
I did not understand your advice about replace, it seems both versions are identical

Comment: can you provide your profile class

Comment: I updated my question with the profile class

Comment: I think its because you have not set `bool isAuthenticated` to true , because of that when you set its value to false it doesn't change its value.To test that theory change `_isAuthenticated` Value to true.

Answer (score -1):

Navigator push named -> logout route?

Comment: where? please explain better your answer